# .NET C# - Passing parent controls to a pagination .ascx control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, user-controls, pagination

On a project I'm working on, I have many <asp:ListView> controls, which are paginated using <asp:DataPager> controls. Instead of copying and pasting the  controls to each .aspx page where I have a paginated list, would it be possible to break out the <asp:DataPager> controls into a reusable/modular .ascx control and create a field on it to pass in the PagedControlID?

I've tried this in the past but couldn't not seem to target the PagedControlID in the Parent page.

Here's what I've got so far. Any help would be much appreciated.

### .aspx Page

```
<abc:Pagination ID="uxPagination" ListControlID="uxEventListView" runat="server" />
```

### .ascx Pagination Control

```
<asp:DataPager ID="uxDataPager" PageSize="1" runat="server" />
```

### .ascx.cs Pagination Control

```
public partial class ABC_UserControls_Pagination : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private string listControlID;

    public string ListControlID
    {
        get { return listControlID; }
        set { listControlID = value; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ListControlID))
        {
            uxDataPager.PagedControlID = ListControlID;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't the `DataPager` already a broken out reusable control that enables paging?

Comment: You're right, it is. But I plan on adding more logic to the DataPager control to make it more customized so I'd like to take a DRY approach and break it out so I do not have duplicate code throughout the site.

Comment: Have you considered extending the DataPager with whatever custom logic you want and then using that control on all the pages?

Comment: That's a good idea. I was, however, able to solve the issue. Since I can't answer I'll just post a link to PasteBin. I've added an OnInit event to the asp:DataPager - http://pastebin.com/Kn6Asrks

Comment: Why not create a Web User Control that contains a ListView and a DataPager?

Comment: @白ジェームス Because the ListViews throughout the site have different templates.

Comment: @DylanM - OK - does my answer solve the problem?  I'm still confused on what error you are getting.

Comment: @白ジェームス - I've solved the issue which is noted in the PasteBin link above. I've also removed the private backing field, as someone noted to me that it was not needed.

Comment: @Dylan - if your question is solved, either post your own answer or delete the question.

Comment: @白ジェームス - I'm unable to post my own answer for another 6 hours. I'll post an answer then.

Comment: Please post the answer now. People are still spending time to read this question only to find that it is already solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies about the delay. This seemed to do the trick. Now with your UserControl you will be able to pass through a control ID (in my case a ListView) and your preferred item count per page.

```
public partial class ABC_UserControls_Pagination : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public string ListControlID { get; set; }
    public int ListPageCount { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void uxDataPager_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        uxDataPager.PagedControlID = ListControlID;
        uxDataPager.PageSize = ListPageCount;
    }

    protected void uxDataPager_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Custom Logic Here
    }
}
```